# .Net 4.6 framework dll trying to load it's netstandard2.1 dependency

Tags: asp.net, dll, .net-4.8, .net-standard-2.1

This 'Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces' have dependencies on .NETFramework v4.6.2, .NETStandard v2.0 and v2.1. This dll is used in .NETFramework v4.8 application while accessing this dll i throws exception '**Could not load file or assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.**'. Here i don't understand why it is trying to load netstandard 2.1 dll in a .NETFramework 4.8 application, so it is not supported or is it possible to skip loading the netstandard 2.1 dependency using config?. Please clarify this issue.

In the `InnerException` and **FusionLog** log message says, it tries to load the netstandard v2.1 dll from different locations.

[image]

**Fusion Log:**

[image]

**.NETStandard v2.1 dependency:**

[image]

Comment: Cannot reproduce this with a simple .NET Framework 8.0 project. You might have to enable MSBuild bin log to dig further into the build process.